# Why doesn't the pressed state of a ColorStateList work with a ListView item?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-resources, android-drawable

I am trying to set up a `ListView` with items that have varying background colors, so my adapter's `getView()` method calls `setBackgroundResource()` with an appropriate drawable resource for the desired background color.

If I use a `ColorDrawable` that references a `ColorStateList` as its color, the color for the pressed state from the `ColorStateList` is not drawn when I tap on the item.

If I use a `StateListDrawable` that references a `ColorDrawable` for the pressed state and a different `ColorDrawable` for the unpressed state, I get the desired highlighting effect when I tap on the item.

I've set up a simple project to demonstrate this. Here is the `getView()` method from the `ListAdapter`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View retval = getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView)retval.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    textView.setText("" + position);

    switch ( position ) {
        case 0:
            retval.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_background_item_0);
            break;

        case 1:
            retval.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_background_item_1);
            break;
    }

    return retval;
}
```

res/drawable/list_background_item_0.xml:

```
<color xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/list_background_item_0" />
```

res/color/list_background_item_0.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/list_background_item_0_pressed"/>
    <item android:color="@color/list_background_item_0_default"/>
</selector>
```

res/drawable/list_background_item_1.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_background_item_1_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_background_item_1_default" />
</selector>
```

res/drawable/list_background_item_1_default.xml:

```
<color xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:color="@color/list_background_item_1_default" />
```

res/drawable/list_background_item_1_pressed.xml:

```
<color xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:color="@color/list_background_item_1_pressed" />
```

res/values/colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="list_background_item_0_default">#FFCCCC</color>
    <color name="list_background_item_0_pressed">#996666</color>
    <color name="list_background_item_1_default">#CCFFCC</color>
    <color name="list_background_item_1_pressed">#669966</color>
</resources>
```

List item 0 is configured with a `ColorDrawable` that references a `ColorStateList` and does not display a highlight when pressed. List item 1 is configured with a `StateListDrawable` and does display the highlight.

I would much rather use the `ColorStateList` than the `StateListDrawable` as it seems cleaner and involves one less file per item type. Is there something I have missed that would let me use this method? If it isn't intended to work as I am expecting, can someone explain why?

Comment: Excellent, well explained question.

Comment: I notice for item_0 that your `<color>` xml in the drawable folder has the same name as the `<selector>` xml in the color folder. Since it's just a color definition, have you tried renaming the first xml file so it too can go in the color folder. I would not have thought it matters, but it's worth a try. Just thinking that may be confusing the system, resulting in the unexpected behavior.

Comment: A `ColorDrawable` is a very simple drawable, it can't manage the state of a complex drawable(like `StateListDrawable` which extends `DrawableContainer`). And, I don't think the first version is cleaner, wrapping one drawable around a state list drawable vs using the same single state list drawable pointing to the right colors(which for some reason you didn't do and decided to wrap the basic colors in color xml drawables).

Comment: @SoundConception - Thanks for the suggestion. I renamed the res/color/list_background_item_0.xml to not overload the ID, but it made no difference.

Comment: @Luksprog - Although simple, the `ColorDrawable` can reference a `ColorStateList` as its color and it picks up the default color just fine, just not the pressed color. I wasn't aware that the drawables referenced in the `StateListDrawable` could just be colors, though. Thanks for the pointer. That indeed makes the `StateListDrawable` solution much more palatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [Luksprog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493939/luksprog)'s comment, I've learned that the drawables referenced by the `StateListDrawable` can be colors from `colors.xml`. This makes the `StateListDrawable` solution preferable to the `ColorStateList` version.

The final solution is...

`getView()` method:

- **no changes**

res/color/list_background_item_0.xml:

- **deleted**

res/drawable/list_background_item_0.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/list_background_item_0_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_background_item_0_default" />
</selector>
```

res/drawable/list_background_item_1.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/list_background_item_1_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_background_item_1_default" />
</selector>
```

res/drawable/list_background_item_1_default.xml:

- **deleted**

res/drawable/list_background_item_1_pressed.xml:

- **deleted**

res/values/colors.xml:

- **no changes**

This solution is as clean or cleaner than I expected the `ColorStateList` version to be had it worked.